# zooming pie-chart

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

> Is there any other way to zoom in/out `piechart` which should not affect
>   the labels (displayed outside of chart) and legend.I tried the following concept,

I have created the `piechart` using the library **com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2** .

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/piechart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added the `ontouchlistener` as follows,

```
public class MyScaleGestures implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {
    private View view;
    private ScaleGestureDetector gestureScale;
    private float scaleFactor = 1;
    public MyScaleGestures(Context c,View view){
        gestureScale = new ScaleGestureDetector(c, this);
        this.view=view;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
    if(scaleFactor<0.01)
        scaleFactor=0.01f;
    view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
    view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
    return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {return true;}
    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {  }
}
```

And I used that `gesturelistener` like,

```
final ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new MyScaleGestures(this,pieChart));
relativelayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                           scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                           return true;
                        }
                    });
```

But the result is,the pie chart is scaled with the labels. I need the **label text size and legend text size as constant** .They should not be scaled. I have used custom  `Scale Gesture Listener`since I read in one post that **Piechart doesn't have method for scaling on pinch in that library**

Comment: Put your layout xml

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Looks like is not possible because labels and legend are inside the chart, why don't you just restrict the maximum zoom?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?